# return PDF in ajax request and open in new window

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I have a ajax request to apiurl where i am getting an PDF File. Now i want to display this file in a new window

```
$("#pdfurl").click(function (e) {
    var Pdfurl = $(this).attr('data-href');
    $.ajax({
        url: "../RequestPages/PreviewPdf",
        type: "GET",
        data: { "pdfUrl": Pdfurl },
        success: function (data) { 
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        }
    });
})



 public ActionResult PreviewPdf(string pdfUrl)
{
    var web = new WebClient();
    byte[] bytes = web.DownloadData(pdfUrl);
    string mimeType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + "a.pdf");
    return File(bytes, mimeType);
}`
```

Comment: `<a href="../RequestPages/PreviewPdf?pdfUrl=bla/pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a>`

Comment: if you look at the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit it will show you how to mimic a form submit which will return the file result like you want with a save dialog or just open the file.

Comment: @mplungjan thanks it worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pragmatic in me suggests

```
<a href="../RequestPages/PreviewPdf?pdfUrl=bla.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a>
```

Never use script if it is not necessary

Answer (score 5):

The point of an AJAX request is to give you the response as Javascript data.

If you want the browser to navigate to the response, you can't use AJAX.

Instead, just use `open()` to open the URL directly.